# Ruby CSV Compare Two CSV Files

Tags: ruby, csv

I have two CSV files with the same headers. I'd like to compare these files and return entries that are missing from the second file. Here's an example:

file1.csv

```
fname,lname,city,state
Joe,Smith,Dallas,TX
Jane,Done,Baltimore,MD
Frank,Jones,Plano,TX
```

file2.csv

```
fname,lname,city,state
Joe,Smith,Dallas,TX
Jane,Done,Baltimore,MD
```

Here's my code:

```
# Returns True if a match is found
# and False if none is found
def find_in_csv(csv_text,search_column,search_string)
  csv_text.find {|row|
    return row[search_column] == search_string
  }
end
```

How do I extend this function to allow returning missing lines?

Comment: If you simply want the lines in `file1.csv` that are not present in `file2.csv` you can use [IO#readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines): `IO.readlines('file2.csv', chomp: true) - IO.readlines('file1.csv', chomp: true)  #=> ["Joe,Smith,Dallas,TX"]` (i.e., no need for CSV methods).

Answer (score 2):

This will return an array of rows which are present in file1.csv but missed in file2.csv

```rb
csv1 = CSV.read("file1.csv")
csv2 = CSV.read("file2.csv")

csv1 - csv2
```

Comment: To be clear, this returns `[["Frank", "Jones", "Plano", "TX"]]`, whereas the corresponding lines (here just the one line) of `file1.csv` are `["Joe,Smith,Dallas,TX\n"]`. The question is not clear about which of these arrays is wanted.